# Induced homomorphism of a linear cocycle

Tags: algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand Example 2.9 in Marcelo Viana's book *Lectures on Lyapunov Exponents*. The relevant details (as far as I can tell) are as follows:

Let $S^1=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ and let $f:S^1\to S^1$ be continuous. Fix any $A_0\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and define $R_{2\pi\alpha(x)}\in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ to be the rotation by the angle $2\pi\alpha(x)$, where $\alpha:S^1\to S^1$ is continuous. Write $A(x) = A_0R_{2\pi\alpha(x)}$. We can define a map $F:S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^1\to S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^1$ by $F(x,[v]) = (f(x), [A(x)v])$. The author appears to claim that for $(\eta,\zeta)\in \pi_1(S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^1)=\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$, we have
$$
F_*(\eta,\zeta)=(\mathrm{deg}(f)\eta, \zeta+2\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)),
$$
where $F_*$ is the induced homomorphism $\pi_1(S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^1)\to \pi_1(S^1\times\mathbb{RP}^1)$.
The $\mathrm{deg}(f)\eta$ is essentially from the definition of degree, but I am quite mystified by the $\zeta+2\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)$ term. Where does this come from?

Also, if anyone knows the original source for this example, I would love to read it. The author attributes it to Michael Herman but gives no reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: the formula is wrong as stated. It should read
$$
F_*(\eta,\zeta) =(\mathrm{deg}(f)\eta,\zeta+2\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)\eta).
$$
We compute the images of the homotopy classes of the loops $a(t)=(t,[(1,0)])$ and $b(t)=(0,e^{i\pi t})$ under $F_*$. Note that $[B\gamma(t)]=[\gamma(t)]$ for any loop $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and any $B\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$, and note that $S^1$ is a 2-fold cover for $\mathbb{RP}^1$. It follows that
$$F_*[a(t)] = \left[(f(t),[e^{2\pi i\alpha(t)}])\right]\longleftrightarrow (\mathrm{deg}(f),2\mathrm{deg}(\alpha))\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$
F_*[(b(t)]=\left[(f(0),[e^{i\pi t}])\right]\longleftrightarrow (0,1)\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Since $[a(t)]\longleftrightarrow(1,0)$ and $[b(t)]\longleftrightarrow(0,1)$, we are done.